# What is the easiest way to get truth table of logical expression?

Tags: notebooks, boolean-computation, logic

I remember that some time ago when I entered a logical expression like $a\wedge b$ in the notebook there was an option (button or menu selection or etc.) to click and generate truth table for it without any programming. I don't remember where that option located. Can anybody please help me find it?

Comment: [`BooleanTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanTable.html)? Also [Create Truth Tables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/CreateTruthTables.html) and [Truth Table on mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruthTable.html).

Comment: @corey979 Where `BooleanTable` is exactly located? Where to click?

Comment: What do you mean _where to click_? It's usage is described in the docs, in the given link.

Comment: @corey979 Ohh. I see. But I remember that there was some option that right after I type boolean expression there was a button to click to generate truth tables without using any additional code. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @No. I just typed logical expression and there was somewhere a button (or menu selection or etc.) that I click and got truth table. It was very convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a truth table for expression in Notebook:

1. Type expression. For example, $a\wedge b$
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. In the suggestion bar press `truth table`
   [image]

---

**Original answer:**

Not worth enabling it **(*)** for that but it's a suggestion bar that you are looking for:

[image]

(*) [Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/5478)

Comment: Yes. It is what I am looking for. Thank you. I will edit your post to describe how to calculate truth table that way step by step.

Comment: By the way, why it does not worth to be enabled?

Comment: @vasili111 source added.