# How to test all possible input for a logic function?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I have a logic expression:
`f0[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_] := a0 And Not a1 And Not a2 And a3 Or Not  a0 And a2 And a3 Or Not a0 And a1 And a3`, I know I should use `BooleanTable`, but it cannot generate a table like below.

How to generate a truth table in mathematica like below?

[image]

Comment: There is the `BooleanTable` command. Does it help? For creating the corresponding function you can use  logical and: `&&` and logical or: `||` in case you don't know.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist Thank you, I have correct my expression, Of course `BooleanTable` can help me, but it cannot generate a table like the picture above, it only returns a series of true or false.

Comment: Then use the `TableForm` with the option `TableHeadings` for the result. Something like: `TableForm[{{a, b, c, d}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"a0", "a1", "a2", "a3"}}]`

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist, thank you, but how to use my function to generate all series of possible outputs like this? I know that how to generate one possible output commad: `TableForm[{{True, False, True, False, f0[True, False, True, False]}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b0"}}]`

Answer (score 2):

`f = a0 && ! a1 && ! a2 && a3`

`TableForm[BooleanTable[{a0, a1, a2, a3, f}, {a0, a1, a2, a3}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {a0, a1, a2, a3, f}}]`

Apparently there are resources like [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruthTable.html) or [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180111/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-truth-table-of-logical-expression?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much! This absolutely solve my quesiton!

Answer (score 1):

```
truthTableFormattor[rawData_] := Insert[Insert[
Grid[rawData /. {0 -> 0, 
   1 -> Item[1, Background -> Lighter[Magenta]]}, 
 FrameStyle -> Gray, 
 Frame -> All], {Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[0.7], {White}}}, 
 Dividers -> {Black, {2 -> Black}}, Frame -> True, 
 Spacings -> {2, {2, {0.7}, 2}}}, 2], {Dividers -> All, 
Spacings -> .7 {1, 1}}, 2];


truthTable[f__] :=  Module[{}, atoms = Cases[Most[{f}],
 (a_ /;Length[a] == 0 \[And] Not[StringQ[a]])];heads = 
 ToString[TraditionalForm@#] & /@ {f};
  rawData = Transpose@Boole[BooleanTable[#, atoms] & /@ {f}];
  If[Last[{f}] === 1, 
   Transpose@Boole[BooleanTable[#, atoms] & /@ Most[{f}]], 
    If[Last[{f}] === "rev", 
    truthTableFormattor[{ToString[
       TraditionalForm@#] & /@ (Most@{f})}~Join~
      Transpose[(Reverse /@ 
      Boole[BooleanTable[#, atoms] & /@ (Most@{f})])]], 
     truthTableFormattor[{heads}~Join~rawData]]]];




f0[a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_] := a0 \[And] \[Not] a1 \[And] \[Not] a2 \[And] a3;

truthTable[a0, a1, a2, a3, f0[a0, a1, a2, a3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow your answer is more perfect